# approach/advice on making git accessible as a public repo

Tags: git

I'm trying to introduce git to my company.  We are an SVN shop.  All devs except me are on Windows (I use a mac)

I've only used git via hosted github before, but that isn't an option because the powers that be are paranoid about the source code.

Anyway, I installed git on a Linux server (after much pain).

My thinking is:

-this git linux server will be our "central" server.  Basically, the tests via Jenkins will be run on this machine and if they pass, promoted to the SVN repo (which the company considers the "real" repo.  I have a git user and figure that the repo will reside in the git user's home directory.

-no one will check any code into SVN, the only way the code gets promoted from git to SVN is if all the tests pass.

Questions:

- does this approach make sense?
- what should I use for a
  protocol?  Looks like I have 3 protocol choices:  git, ssh, and http
- best I can tell, I need to set up the git-daemon.  I'm not sure
  how to do this as every article I find is very unclear on how to do
  this and what do do (broken links, commands that don't work, etc)
- should every user have their own account on the linux server?

I'm not as worried about figuring out git-svn, first thing I want is just to be able so pull/push from multiple dev machines.

thanks for any thoughts!

Comment: Paranoid about the source code? Like, that github will steal all your secrets?

Comment: company just isn't comfortable hosting at external source.  security holes, github screws up and doesn't back things up properly, etc.  typical thinking at a large company.  And of course just a couple weeks ago there was a major breach at github.

Comment: You should try to use gitosis http://scie.nti.st/2007/11/14/hosting-git-repositories-the-easy-and-secure-way. But those Windows dev machines this is what scares me most :)

Comment: Well I guess the recent breach isn't going to help your case, but you can totally play the "every developer has a full backup on their machine" card...

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using SVN and plan on continue doing that, your best bet is to use `Smart HTTP` setup so that you can leverage your existing servers and know-how to serve Git - http://progit.org/2010/03/04/smart-http.html

You will be able to have a git server setup with authentication pretty much similar to what you are doing with SVN and things should be fine.

This also helps you from users point of view. Usage of http served git repo is not going to be very different from a http served SVN repo ( serving SVN with http is the most common that I have seen ).

The mirroring between Git and SVN that you are looking at should probably be avoided as it brings in more complexity. A git repo can be the "real repo" that you describe and you can push from the "dev" git repo to the "real" one once builds pass. Git is a DVCS and will help in such a setup.

Comment: Good to know.  From what I read I should get git or ssh going first before I tackle HTTP.  HTTP is definitely not the normal approach (unfortunately).  Once I get git:// or ssh working as I will look at http://